# How to get the last sql errno for a pymysql connection?

Tags: python, mysql, connection-pooling, pymysql

I use pymysql to interact with MySQL database and implement a connection pool. Now the problem is how can i evict the broken connections when they are returned to the pool? I do not want to issue a ping or 'select 1' command to check the validation each time getting a connection from the pool as it will introduce performance penalty.

So i wonder if there is a way or flag i can check when a connection is returned to the pool: does the last executed sql raise a exception and what's the errno? Then i can check the errno to get to know whether a connection is broken and do a reconnect.

So far, one way to achieve this is to introduce an extra argument to the close() method to indicate the errno if exception happened when the client returns the connection.

```
errno = None
try:
    conn = pool.get_connection()
    conn.execute(sql)
exception pymysql.Error, e:
    errno = e.args[0]
finally:
    conn.close(errno)
```

But i would more like the client code to keep consistent with other pools, any more graceful ways?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i implements a custom database connection class and introduce an errno member to record the last sql executed error number. Then each time returning a connection to the pool, i first check the errno value and if it equals to 2006 or 2013, i kick off this broken connection.